# Adding css animation to span in text

Tags: css, animate.css

I have a paragraph on my site, off which I want certain words to pulse with animate.css. I have successfully added animate.css to my site, however, when I try to add it to my span class, it is not working. I did some research and it seems like you have to add a display to the span, since animate.css doesn't work if if the display is not working. Here's my code:

```css
.animatespan {
  display: -moz-inline-stack;
  display: inline-block !important;
  zoom: 1;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1>
  Text that is not supposed to animate 
  <span style="color:#4ceb90" class="animated pulse animatespan">pulsing word</span>
  Text that is not supposed to animate
  <span style="color:#4ceb90" class="animated pulse animatespan">pulsing word</span>
  Text that is not supposed to animate
  <span style="color:#4ceb90" class="animated pulse animatespan">pulsing word.</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: You should read this https://css-tricks.com/animate-to-an-inline-style/

Answer (score 2):

You only need to say `inline-block` the code was working expected it's just that it was pulsing once and then stopping.

Adding infinite means it will keep repeating the animation.

You can read the documentation [here.](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css)

```css
.animatespan {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1>
  Text that is not supposed to animate 
  <span style="color:#4ceb90" class="animated pulse infinite animatespan">pulsing word</span>
  Text that is not supposed to animate
  <span style="color:#4ceb90" class="animated pulse infinite animatespan">pulsing word</span>
  Text that is not supposed to animate
  <span style="color:#4ceb90" class="animated pulse infinite animatespan">pulsing word.</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand it's because the span isn't displayed inline-block;

so you would need to do the following:

```
.animatespan {
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: top;
}
h1 span {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Here is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/8ea9armk/1/

i've added an extra css class named animated, which will make the pulse run on an infinite loop.